# How to change position of Add to Cart Button on Single Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change position of Add to Cart Button on Single Product. I've tried to used code below:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
               'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
            'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 9);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with My Theme. The result is that Add to Cart Button is double. The screenshot below:

[Add cart button displaying twice with My Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FbZJ.png)

When I change the Theme to different one (Twenty Nineteen),  every thing seems to be okey. The screenshot below:

[Add car button displaying once with Twenty Nienteen Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfe89.png)

My website is www.applefix.pl. Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to "delay" the actions after the parent theme is loaded:

```
function wc_move_single_product_button() { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 9);
}; 

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wc_move_single_product_button', 20 );
```

Update: another possibility is that your theme uses another function to hook the button. I would try to use the WordPress default theme just to check if that’s the case. If it is, you can search the function and unhook it properly!

Let me know if it does the trick!

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work.  The result is the same. I'm using a Code Snippets to put a code. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Another possibility is that your theme uses another function to hook the button. I would try to use the WordPress default theme just to check is that’s the case. If it is, you can search the function and unhook it properly!

Comment: Definitely that's the problem. I've tried to change to different theme and it is working good. Could you tell me how can I find this function?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer then. You can find the function searching your theme files for "woocommerce_single_product_summary" as the function should be hooked to that action. Then remove that hook using remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'your_theme_function name', 30 ); 

Note that the last value (30) is the priority, so if the theme uses a different one you should match it to remove the action.